# Is there a canonical way to mix standard django sitemaps with Wagtail sitemaps?

Tags: django, wagtail

Pretty straightforward - I want to use the django sitemap framework and set up my static and custom pages, and I want to make sure that any pages added in wagtail are also indexed.

Answer (score 0):

[Wagtail's sitemaps module](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html) will only generate sitemaps for pages managed by Wagtail. But it should be possible to enable [Django sitemaps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) alongside it for everything else and link the two together with a [sitemap index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en).